# Gauss law and its application on irregular figures

Tags: electrostatics, symmetry, gauss-law

According to the Gauss’s law the flux due to external charge always remains zero. Also the total flux is given by the charge enclosed/ epsilon. So consider this surface,what is the fate of the flux which is highlighted and is thick in the diagram. According to me with respect to second surface the charge seems external so that flux can be neglected? And in that case how will gauss’s law hold?

[image]

Comment: This post is not a duplicate as I have modified the figure and made it clear about what I am asking.

Comment: what's the problem with flux here?

Comment: The 'fate' of the flux is to enter the left hand volume and then leave the left hand volume...

Comment: @JEB Will that flux be counted  while calculating the integral of E.dS

Comment: If you wish, yes, but then you also have to take care to treat that flux then exiting the enclosed volume once again...

Comment: @JonCuster what I meant was, it left the right hand volume, and entered the left hand volume. Will this effect cancel the net flux. Since they are same shape.

Comment: And where does it go from there? If you integrate over the surface, you have to integrate over _all_ of your defined surface, not just various bits of it.

Comment: @JonCuster if this structure were a cube there wouldn’t be any difference right?

Comment: This is a duplicate. I see no significant improvement in the labelling of the figure. What are you integrating over to calculate the flux?

Comment: @kricheli what do you imply by labelling? I am not integrating but I just wanted to know if that flux is counted when the total flux is found.

Comment: What is "that flux"? What area you are using is still unclear to me in the figure. The flux is not an arrow (like the you marked thick).

Comment: @kricheli by flux I meant field line and the area you can see in the first figure it is going perpendicular to one parallel to xz plane.

Comment: Flux doesn't have a fate. Flux is field lines crossing a surface, so it doesn't go anywhere, it is defined at the surface, according to the surface and the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is "the *total* flux from external charges is zero." So any field line that enters your volume from an external charge must also exit your volume. It is not "neglect fluxes from external charges" or "no flux from any external charge can go through any surface" (not sure which of those two you were using).

Also, note that when the field line you point out exits your volume, it counts as positive flux, and when it reenters, it counts as negative flux, and then it exits again, and again counts as positive flux. So in some sense you're correct. The contribution to total flux from reentering and reexiting the volume is similar to how an external charge would behave - it deosn't change the total flux.

And finally, Gauss' law still applies to this strange volume. If you correctly calculated $\int E\cdot \hat{n}dS$, you would get $q/\epsilon_0$ - but only if you note that $E\cdot \hat{n}$ can be negative in some places if the electric field points into rather than out of the box. You don't need to make some distinction between which electric fields are from internal vs external sources and make sure not to count the external ones - that's not a thing. But typically when we use gauss' law, we use *convenient* volumes/surfaces. Where some symmetry allows us to actually calculate the electric field from knowing something about the total flux.

Answer (score -2):

> According to the Gauss’s law the flux due to external charge always remains zero.

This statement is valid for a closed surface. Which the surface in your example (the highlighted part) does not seem to be. So no contradiction with Gauß' law...

Edit: Also, obviously, you need to start with a closed surface, something that divides $\mathbb{R}^3$ into two disconnected regions, to actually be able to reasonably use the word "external charge".

Comment: wrt second surface it seems like flux is external right ?